# I am to install CiviCRM on Windows 10 with WAMP

Tags: installation, issues, windows

I have been trying to setup CiviCRM on Windows 10,  But I am not able to install "bin/civi-download-tools" on it. Even I have installed and enabled Linux subsystem tools on windows.

Please guide me as I am to complete my test.

Comment: Hi Syed, your step by step guide is the System Administrator Guide. You can find it at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/.

Comment: Can you please specifically guide me the page?

Comment: @syed - it will help if you tell the folk (who are voluntarily trying to help you) what it is that you have already tried

Answer (score 1):

BuildKit does not work on Windows at present - CiviCRM BuildKit makes many assumptions about what tools and environment it has access to and at this time it is not Windows compatible.

It could be made to be so but the ease of setting up a Linux VM in Windows and the ever-improving "Windows Subsystem for Linux" make it unlikely that any explicit efforts are going to be made to make BuildKit natively support running on Windows/WAMP stacks.